# I simply can't change python unicode

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm working with flask and sqlalchemy to print a list in an html page. Code is below
 Python code:

```
@app.route('/restaurants')
def showRestaurants():
   restaurant = session.query(Restaurant.name)
   return render_template('restaurants.html', restaurant = restaurant)
```

Html code:

```
<ul>
  {% for i in range(0,9) %}
  <li>
   <strong><a href="#">{% print(restaurant[i]) %}</a></strong>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Page:

```
(u'Urban Burger',)
(u'Super Stir Fry',)
(u'Panda Garden',)
(u'Thyme for That Vegetarian Cuisine ',)
(u"Tony's Bistro ",)
(u"Andala's",)
(u"Auntie Ann's Diner ",)
(u'Cocina Y Amor ',)
(u'State Bird Provisions',)
```

So, what am I doing wrong? I have a database with restaurant names and wanna make a list of it but it seems impossible to decode it. I've already tried .encode() which print out an error says the variable encode is not define and when I put in create_engine encoding = 'acsii' simply does nothing. I appreciate any help.

Comment: have you tried this `print(restaurant[i].encode('UTF-8', 'strict'))`?

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy's `session.query` returns a list of tuples. So, to display the name of each restaurant, you'd want to access the string in the first element of each tuple.

```
   <strong><a href="#">{% print(restaurant[i][0]) %}</a></strong>
```

Comment: Another option is query.all() which will return a list of the resulting values, so in this case a list of strings.  Still need the same treatment of running through the list for output however.

Answer (score 0):

encode('ascii') will work, but you have to apply it to the unicode string.  The problem you have right now is that you are printing out a tuple not a string.

Instead, try referencing the restaurants like this:

```
restaurant[i][0].encode('ascii')
```

Even `restaurant[i][0]` might render correctly.